# How to use -keep class with two sets of package

Tags: proguard

I am using proguard 2.4 and I am trying to do something maybe tricky.
I would like to obfusce only two sets of package, let's say my.first.package.* and my.second.package.* but keep every others and their calls non-obfusced.

To do this, I added this in my proguard.conf :

```
-keep class !my.first.package.** { *; }
-keep class !my.second.package.** { *; }
```

But it's not working, it looks like they are interacting with each other. But it works if I have only one of them. Is there any way to specify this with some kind of an "and" condition ? Like :

```
-keep class !my.first.package.** OR !my.second.package.** { *; }
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response to myself, I had to do it in one line

```
-keep class !my.first.package.**,!my.second.package.** { *; }
```